# JS variable value not displaying in html

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to display the js variable inside an html tag. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("newvalue"));            
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<details>
    <summary>Section 1</summary>
    <p><b>Value: <p id="test1"></p></b></p> 
</details>
```

The value of id=test1 is not displaying in my web page. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: is the script tag imported before the details element?

Comment: it might be that the javascript code is running before the page is loaded. If that is the case you should see an error in the browser's console. :)

Comment: You can't nest p tags in p tags. http://community.sitepoint.com/t/p-inside-p/8402

Comment: If the problem described by toskv is not that case, you should check if `localStorage.getItem("newvalue")` returns a value.

Comment: Perfect. After placing the script below details tag, everything worked. Thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As 9Deuce said above in the comments, you can't nest p tags in p tags. Try changing it to:

```
<span id="test1"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

```
<script>
document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("newvalue"));            
</script>
```

is on the button of your page, just before the `</body>` tag.
Your script is probably loaded before your DOMs.
Also/else, try to use a `<span>` instead of `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

[It Works](https://jsfiddle.net/5srfubL4/)

Either make sure the DOM call is at the bottom of your page, or call it on jQuery.ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("newvalue"));            
});
```